# Module Build Failed. TypeError: this.getResolve is not a function

Tags: angular, sass, sass-loader, webpack-3

I am getting this error when compiling sass.

**webpack**: 3.12.0, **sass-loader**: 8.0.0.

Also, I use angular2.

```
     {
        test: /\.(scss|sass)$/,
        use: [
          "to-string-loader",
          {
            loader: "css-loader",
            options: {
              sourceMap: false
            }
          },
          {
            loader: "sass-loader",
              options: {
                  sourceMap: false
              }
            }
        ]
      }
```

Answer (score 58, accepted):

Probably a SASS/Webpack compatibility issue.
Downgrading to `"sass-loader": "^7.3.1",` solved it for me.

Comment: You might also need to downgrade 'node-sass' to `"node-sass": "^4.14.1"`.